# Find a field that contains text but give preference to matches at the start of the field

Tags: mysql

It's very simple problem.

I'd like to find records where a text field contains text to populate an autocomplete field in a form. The challenge is that I'd like to limit the results to the first 20 records, but give preference to matches that are at the start of the field.

How I do this now is I execute a query for `field LIKE "%term"` for 10, and then append records where `field LIKE "%term%"` for 10. It requires two searches.

Is it possible to do this with just one query of the table? Ordering by the position of the match in the field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to order by the first occurrence of the search string. (I assume you wanted to write field LIKE "term%".)

```
SELECT *, LOCATE('term', field) as rev_score FROM table WHERE field LIKE "%term%" ORDER BY rev_score DESC LIMIT 20;
```

However most likely this query will be much slower than the field "term%" (assuming you have an index on field).

- In your case the field LIKE "term%" could be fulfilled by indexes on field resulting in a range query but still fast.
- field LIKE "%term%" LIMIT 10 if you don't use order still can be fast(er). Statistically 2 times faster than the solution I wrote depending on the search term and data distribution. The reason is because MySQL will start to scan through the table searching for "term" (no indexes can be used here). When it found the 10 elements it will stop. This can be in the beginning the table.
- What I wrote will cause MySQL to do a full scan on the *whole* table and check *every* row for "term" than to a filesort on the calculated value. Probably the worst thing which can happen on a single table lookup.

I would say try both version and go with the faster one. Or if your dataset is big you can checkout Full Text Search capabilities of MySQL (MYISAM has it and InnoDB supports it too since MySQL 5.6).

Comment: +1 . I like this one which will sort depending on where the term is located in the word !!

Comment: it's a shame that SQL has to eval the entire table to order it, but it's understandable. If I can narrow my search with WHERE conditions the performance might not be an issue.

Comment: It only has to if there's no adequate indexes are present which is in this case evident as it is calculated so impossible to have indexes.

Indeed, if you are able to narrow with extra conditions that might be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Smart! I don't know if it's possible, but I know how you can do it a little bit better:

```
<?php

$q = 'term';
$limit = 20;

$first = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE name LIKE '%$q' ORDER BY name LIMIT $limit");
$first_len = !$sql?0:mysql_num_rows($first);
$limit -= $first_len;
$second = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE name LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT $limit");
$second_len = !$sql?0:mysql_num_rows($second);

if (!$first_len && !$second_len) {
    exit('No results found.');
}

function handleSearchResultRow($row) {
    echo $row['name'].'<br/>';
}

if ($first_len)
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($first))
        handleSearchResultRow($row);

if ($second_len)
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($second))
        handleSearchResultRow($row);

?>
```

Tada! You'll get the same result, but with slightly more code! This will make sure that there will always be up to 20 results, with the results starting with the term first!

If you really would like "Ordering by the position of the match in the field", then I think you'll have to create an array of all results and sorting it with php strpos(). But SQL is really powerful, and probably has the power to do this too. Please post another answer and tell me if you find out how to do that. :)

Comment: This is kind of what I'm doing already. I'm looking for pure SQL solution since it's just an ordering issue. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%term%' order by IF(field REGEXP '^term.*',0,1),field LIMIT 20;
```